# Debugging unit tests run on cmd line using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, debugging, maven

I have a fairly large project which has many dependencies, as a result, I won't be able to build it on Eclipse. I am using Maven and I can build the project on command line. I know how to run unit tests on command line.

My question is that is it possible to debug the unit tests running on command line using eclipse?

Comment: If in eclipse you right click your test class in package explorer, I have the option 'Debug As' > 'JUnit Test'. Not sure if you need some plugin first though

Comment: As I said, I am not able to build the project on eclipse, therefore, can't run unit tests on Eclipse. My question was if I can somehow attach eclipse to the unit test process I run from command line so that I can use eclipse GUI to debug the unit tests

Comment: Actually you can do it. I have maven project imported to eclipse and I can run JUnit/TestNG right in IDE. Even can run a partuclar test methods alone - and maven buidler ensures all your changes are picked up before test is started. It seems all you need to do is to install m2e plugin, mvn eclipse:eclipse and import maven project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html) allows for the remote debugging of unit tests.

You simply need to call maven using the following command:

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
```

The tests will automatically pause and await a remote debugger on port 5005. You can then attach to the running tests using Eclipse. You can setup a "Remote Java Application" launch configuration via the menu command "Run" > "Open Debug Dialog..."

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a debugger by creating a remote java application and this application will listen for that particular port on which you will launch your unit test .

Answer (score 0):

We also can run the following command, to debug the test cases for one class only

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestClassName -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
```